# My windows vista freeze in the boot splash screen

Tags: windows-vista

My windows vista freeze in the boot splash screen. This happens even with the install DVD.

My laptop is a DELL M65 and the diagnostics say everything is correct. Memory, disk, irqs, etc.

The diagnostics CD loads fine and I can run the tests, but every windows install cd hangs the machine. A minimal linux distro loads fine.

I had tried safe mode, currently the hard disk is brand new but the install cd freeze in the same place.

Comment: So there is no OS installed on the system? Is there a recovery partition on the hard drive? Have you tried reinstalling the system from it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a defective CPU.